# Finding the threshold at which events become significantly more frequent

Tags: change-point, threshold

I have two sequences of data: air temperature T and event A. High temperatures can cause Event A, or it can just happen randomly (or other reasons). In the database, some events A are attributed to high temperatures, while others aren't (causes not identified). Theoretically, as the temperature goes up, more events should happen. I need to figure out what air temperature value (threshoold) causes a statistically significant increase in events.

Problems:

1. Not every event A can be detected and correctly evaluated as a result of high temperatures, so we'll have fewer events at high temperatures (say 5000 versus 100).  This makes it seem like the event is less likely at high temperatures (which it isn't).
2. How should the threshold be calculated in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most natural processes do not change abruptly, so I would be very careful about working with thresholds. Instead, splines can be used to model nonlinearities, and then inspect the spline fit to determine where it makes sense to place a *decision* threshold. For your additional question, might it make sense to just remove the very high temperatures? Alternatively, you could just fit splines to your entire dataset, then disregard the spurious decline in fitted events for very high temperatures.

Comment: To add to @Stephan Kolassa ‘s good points, cross-validation should be very helpful here. And in case spline modeling proves daunting, scatterplots will be informative as long as designed to prevent overplotted points.